# Is there any default autocomplete option in Angular?

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I tried to use autocomplete in Angular. Searched Stack Overflow and found few packages. When I try to use those package, I face few errors. So Instead of using a package, is there any default autocomplete feature in Angular without using Angular Materials?
[Here I have used select option for testing. Need to move the same options to autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRZIS.png)

Here what I have tried

```
<select class="form-control" name="seg_id" (change)="changeShape($event.target)"> <option *ngFor="let seg of segment" [value]="seg"> {{seg}} </option> </select>
```

Comment: can you add more code to help you further

Comment: What are the errors you are facing? You can post it here with some sample snippet so that we can help on resolving it..

Comment: Now so for I have added a dropsown for showing values.
here is a code for that:

`<select class="form-control" name="seg_id" (change)="changeShape($event.target)">
            <option *ngFor="let seg of segment" [value]="seg">
              {{seg}}
            </option>
        </select>`

Comment: Add **all** relevant code to your question. Comments should be used for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Typeahead**

Follow this [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples)

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable using creating your own auto-complete component

[Ref here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/autocomplete-search-with-angular4-and-firebase/) This is just an example although you need to change few things in order to get your desired functionality. But, you will get some idea out of it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The documentation is about angular4. Is it feasible for angular2?